# Centering HTML Content wider than Browser without Horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

Related questions do not contain helpful answers.

I'm trying to create a headerbar for a website that has a width of 2000 pixels (so wide enough to cover most large screens), but which is centered, but I also do not want the parent container div (which is positioned left 50%) to cause the browser to overflow horizontally.

I can't just "overflow hidden" on the html or body tags, as I am not declaring a specific width (and declaring 100% doesn't hide the overflow).

[image: Overflow depiction]

The code I have looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbgout">
        <div id="navbg"></div>
    </div>

#navbgout {
    width:2000px;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}

#navbg {
    width:2000px;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    background-image:url("images/header_bg.png");
}
```

I've tried putting another parent container around it to provide an overflow:hidden, but nothing works.  If I set that parent to 100% width, it doesn't mask.  If I set it to a fixed value in pixels, it isn't reflexively sized.

This is particularly vexing as the iPad's mobile Safari will read this "overflow" width as true width and zoom the page out extra far to account for it.

Comment: You could always try setting a min-width of the screen. That way you assign a width and can set overflow hidden. If that doesnt work, maybe look into using em instead of px or %. Or even [vh and vw](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) might work for more modern browsers.

Comment: min-width and % won't hide the overflow.  ems are just a different exact measurement like pixels.

Comment: ems are more responsive then px, and usually setting a width is what has allowed me to set overscroll to hidden. If there is no width overscroll hidden wont work.

Comment: And...this would work...if I knew how big the image was *in ems,* otherwise it clips or centers incorrectly.

Comment: You could try using this [tool](http://pxtoem.com/) if you know the images size in px. If that doesnt work have you tryed setting body to `width:100vw; overscroll:hidden;`?

Comment: See original question (short answer: yes).  As for the converter: what the heck is a "base pixel size"?

Comment: % is not the same as vw, I would just go with the default base pixel size, because em is responsive it needs a base pixel to give you the relative em measurement. also it might be helpful if you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Ok, after some fiddling, I had to set it to use a base pixel size of *14px* which appears to be the *font size* that is currently in effect (specified in my body tag as 14px).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the width as 2000px to cater for screensizes. If you set the width as 100% then it will always adjust to the width of the viewport.

Ideally you would set the width as 100%, then add a container class with e.g. `max-width: 1200px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` This will then make the navbar always the width of the viewport but also allow the content to be centered on the screen.

Comment: And...here's what 100% (instead of 2000px) does: http://s15.postimg.org/5mokfzrrf/scrolling2.png
AKA: Does not work.  The width gets truncated *too short* because of the positioning back to the left (so its centered).

Comment: `width: 100%` will cause the width to be 100% of the parent container. The only way that your header would not stretch the full width would be because of a width or max-width being set on the element itself, or on a parent container such as the `body` or `header` tags. 
Could you upload a screenshot with more context on the page such as the whole browser window?

Comment: Here's a stripped down example.  It uses the background images rather than the header bar, but the effect is the same.  http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~mmj29/temp/site/strip.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with 3 different background images positioned absolutely?

Comment: I stripped out the javascript that does the paralax scrolling effect.

Comment: Ok, I still don't see any need to be setting the width as 2000px. This is not good practice as the browser will have to render all the pixels that aren't being viewed. Using width 100% will make the container stretch to the width of the viewport, once you have this you can then add a background image which you can position however you want and can use `background-size: contain` or `background-size: cover` for more options.

Comment: None of this is helping me *center* the image.  The background-size rule only makes the image *scale to fit* the container, which is not what I want.  I want the size to remain constant, but have the *position* update.

Comment: `background-position: center center;`?

Comment: <Peruse old questions that don't have accepted answers> WHY IS THIS NOT MARKED ACCEPTED. Have your 25 rep *two years late* good sir.